# Android - SpeechRecognizer in Serivce - Error 9 but I have all permissions

Tags: android, android-service, speech-recognition

I using SpeechRecognizer in Service, it work only first time when I call `speechRecognizer.startListening()`, and then it has an error with code 9 (insufficient permission).

If in Activity, it work well.

Permissions in my app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Recognizer Intent

```
private val intent by lazy {
        Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH).run {
            putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
            putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
            putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, context.applicationContext.packageName)
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: Try if the solution mentioned here works : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210262/10657559

Comment: @PhongBM Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpeechRecognizer` instead RecognizerIntent. It works in service well. You init it in `OnStartCommand` like this:

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(this,"start Service.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);

    Intent voice = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    voice.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass()
            .getPackage().getName());
    voice.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    voice.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 10);

    speechRecognizer.startListening(voice);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

For more detail : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer

Comment: Thank you. But this way is same my way. It still error with code 9.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to this Service topic but does the official documentation of SpeechRecognizer point out that you can't use it when you're not on the MainThread?

> This class's methods must be invoked only from the main application
> thread.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer

And this might be stupid but did you ask the user for those permissions at runtime?

I should have put this as a comment instead of an answer but the editor of Answer works way better.

Answer (score 0):

Using `createOnDeviceSpeechRecognizer` instead of `createSpeechRecognizer` worked for me in Android 13 (Samsung)

I had provided the microphone permissions for both my and Google app and calling from the main thread but still wasn't working.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer